# Fast way to find out if one value of one column exists in the same table with 2 or 3 other values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, mariadb

I have 3 tables. One for products, one for tags and one for products-tags-associations.
The tags have different levels and work like categories and subcategories, but the tags are not associated directly to each other. The only thing that connects tags to each other (or put a subcategory in a category) are the products.
Imagine I have the product with the id 1, called Apple iPhone 13 Pro Max
It has the following tags:

```
+----+---------------------+-------+
| id | name                | level |
+----+---------------------+-------+
|  1 | Telefoon            |     1 |
|  2 | Apple               |     2 |
|  3 | iPhone 13 Pro Max   |     3 |
```

Which means that the products_tags_association table has these rows in it:

```
+------------+--------+
| product_id | tag_id |
+------------+--------+
|          1 |      1 |
|          1 |      2 |
|          1 |      3 |
```

Because of this combination of information, I now know that the tag "Telefoon" has the tag "Apple" inside it, and the tag "Apple" has the tag "iPhone 13 Pro Max" inside it.
This is how I build the menu on my website.

I now have a problem though, as I have a website with 239 536 rows in the products_tags_association table.
I'm trying to create a step-by step selection tool where they first choose a tag from level 1, then level 2, then level 3, but the tags for each level need to only be the tags that have products which have the selected tag from the previous level.

The logic I have right now is this:

```
    $sql='SELECT tags.id,level, name FROM tags WHERE tags.level="'.$lvl.'";';
    $tags=getDataFromDb($sql,'id');
    if(is_array($tags) && is_array($selectedTagsByLvl) && $lvl>1){
        foreach($tags as $t=>$tg){
            $conditions='';
            if(is_array($selectedTagsByLvl)){
                foreach($selectedTagsByLvl as $l=>$tgs){
                    $conditions.=' AND id IN (SELECT product_id FROM products_tags_association WHERE product_id=products.id AND tag_id IN ('.implode(',',$tgs).'))';
                }
            }
            $sql='SELECT id FROM products WHERE online=1 AND id IN (SELECT product_id FROM products_tags_association WHERE product_id=products.id AND tag_id='.$tg['id'].') '.$conditions.' LIMIT 1;';
            if(!is_array(getDataFromDb($sql))){
                unset($tags[$t]);
            }
        }
        if(count($tags)==0){
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return $tags;
```

So first I get all the tags that have the level I'm selecting right now, and then for each of those tags I check if there is one product that has that tag, plus each of the tags that I've selected in the previous steps. I should only be able to select a few tags per level.
This works, the problem is that it's too slow.

How can I make this faster?

All I need to know is if there is a combination of one product_id with each of the selected tag_id's and the tag_id's for the current level. Maybe something with GROUP BY product_id?

I'm using PHP and mysql (MariaDB)

Comment: "The only thing that connects tags to each other (or put a subcategory in a category) are the products" - that's where you made it wrong. Obviously there must be the parent_id column in the "tags" table (that should be named "categories" not "tags").

Comment: If your paragraph on `Telefoon` is relevant to the problem, please add some data to your sample data to show the relevance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) AS ct
    FROM table
    GROUP BY product_id
```

Then, `ct` tells you how many times each `product_id` shows up in the table.  Tacking on `HAVING ct > 1` to list just the products that occur more than once.

General rule:  When you can do a task in a single SQL statement it is better to do so than shoveling data into the client to have it do the work.  (And usually a lot less coding!)

Comment: Thank you for this. I ended up applying this SQL in my foreach($tags) as follows:
$sql='SELECT products_tags_association.product_id, COUNT(tag_id) AS ct FROM products_tags_association LEFT JOIN products ON products.id=products_tags_association.product_id WHERE products.online=1 AND tag_id IN ('.implode(',',$selectedTagsPlusThisTag).') GROUP BY product_id HAVING ct='.count($selectedTagsPlusThisTag).' LIMIT 1;';
And it is fast enough now!
I always try to do everything in one SQL but in this case it is just too slow, that's why I've separated it and am using PHP to process the data.